# Kepler's third Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, sun

Kepler's third law states $C=\frac{r^3}{T^2}$, as seen from the orbits of planets around the sun. But as the earth also attracts the sun, the sun must also orbit the earth and so $c=\frac{r^3}{T'^2}$ from which we can derive $T'^2=\frac{M}{m}T^2$ or $T'=\sqrt{333000}T$ or about 577 year. If this reasoning is correct how can we observe this rotation. But if it is not correct how can we then apply the third law of Newton to derive the law of gravitation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323183/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. Kepler's third law, as quoted in your question
is not exactly true.

The situation in the two-body problem (sun and one planet)
is more complicated, because both the sun and the planet
orbit around their common barycenter (the $\color{red}{+}$
in the animation below).

[image: animation]
(animated image from [Wikipedia: Barycenter - Gallery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Gallery))

The correct form of [Kepler's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law) for the
two-body problem (sun + one planet) can be derived
from Newton's gravitational law. And the result is:

$$\frac{a^3}{T^2}=\frac{G(M+m)}{4\pi^2}$$
where
$a$ is the semi-major axis of the elliptical relative
motion of one mass relative to the other,
$T$ is the period of the orbit,
$M$ is the mass of the sun,
$m$ is the mass of the planet,
$G$ is Newton's gravitational constant.

Then, because the mass of the sun
is so much larger than the mass of the planet
(i.e. $M\gg m$), we can use the approximation
$$\frac{a^3}{T^2}\approx\frac{GM}{4\pi^2}.$$