# find it period with given mean orbital radius

Tags: homework-and-exercises

A planet has a mean orbital radius of 5.2 Astronomical Units (AU). What is its period?
how do we find it period using the Kepler’s Third Law.

Comment: Read this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592669/keplers-third-law

Comment: The problem is presumably referring to a planet around our Sun. (Did it say that?) Use the fact that Earth has a mean orbital radius of 1 AU and a period of 1 year.